# nav bar made from ul gets jagged edge in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a navbar on the top of my page, made from nested `ul` that gets it's `visibility` changed on mouseover. The thing works and looks okay in firefox, but when I open it in chrome I get a jagged bottom edge and can't figure out why. I use `normalize.css` along with a custom icons font (ionicons), a font from the google library and jquery.

Any help or suggestions appreciated. Snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#content').load('html/landing.html'); //loads landing.html
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/landing.css" type="text/css" />'); //loads landing.css

 //shows dropdown
 function openSubMenu() { 
  $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
 }; 
 //closes dropdown
 function closeSubMenu() { 
  $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
 };

 $('#navbar > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
 $('#navbar > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
});
```

```css
/*************************************
GENERAL STYLE(fonts, bg...)
*************************************/

body {
 font-family: 'Pt Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 background-image: url('../images/mobile-bg.jpeg');
}

html {
 min-width: 320px;
}


/*************************************
BANNER
*************************************/

.banner {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1em 0;
}

.banner h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}



/*************************************
TOP MENU
*************************************/

#navbar {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #913D88;
 text-align: center;
}

#navbar li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

#navbar li a:link, #navbar li a:visited {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #913D88;
 padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
 color: #190b18;
}

#navbar li ul {
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#navbar li ul li {
 display: inline;
}

#storitve {

}



/*************************************
FOOTER
*************************************/

.footer {
 background-color: #913D88;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

.footer p {
 padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
}


/*************************************
LANDSCAPE SMARTPHONE
*************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 body {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('');
 }
 #storitve {

 }

}



/*************************************
TABLET
*************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
 body {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url('');
 }
}



/*************************************
LAPTOP
*************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
 body {
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url('');
 }
}



/*************************************
DESKTOP
*************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
 body {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url('');
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Domača stran znanstveno informacijskega centra</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/frame.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="banner">
    <img src="images/ijs_logo.gif" alt="IJS logo">
    <h1>ZNANSTVENO INFORMACIJSKI CENTER</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="myMenu2">
    <ul id="navbar">
     <li><a href="#">IJS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
      <ul id="storitve">
       <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">ENG</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <p>&copy;&nbsp;ZIC IJS. Vse pravice pridržane</p>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you specify the font-size on the body-element, if you instead directly apply font-size to where you specifically want it it will make the space go away.

In your case simply removing

```
body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

will remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

try relative position should work

```
    #navbar li ul {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```